# this.refresh not working for select2 dropdown

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ui-select2

I have created a select2Select View that allows multiple selection. Now if I select a value from the dropdown and then do `this.refresh()` in corresponding route with an action, the value does not rollback in the view but other select dropdowns like Ember.Select resets the value to default(works as expected).Can anyone suggest if i am doing anything wrong with the created select2Select view because the selection is showing up with previous selected value.

**HBS:**

```
{{view "select2Select"
    content=_content
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    optionLabelPath="content.name"
    placeholder="Select a Value.."
    selection=selected
    multiple=true
}}
```

**select2Select View JS:**

```
App.Select2SelectView = Ember.Select.extend(Em.I18n.TranslateableProperties, {
    classNames: ['form-control'],
    didInsertElement: function() {
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'processChildElements');
    },

    processChildElements: function() {
        this.$().select2({
            placeholder: this.get('placeholder')
        });
    },

    willDestroyElement: function () {
        this.$().select2("destroy");
    }
});
```

**In the Route :**

```
actions: {
   toRoute: function(){
       this.refresh();
   }
}
```